# AngularJS with Ionic, how to use ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-options

I recently started experimenting with AngularJS (and Ionic framework), and I just can't seem to get my dropdowns to work with an array of objects.

I can provide more code if needed, but basically I've got the following object in my controller:

```
$scope.availableCarParks = [{ 'Id': '1', 'Name': 'Parking1' },{ 'Id': '2', 'Name': 'Parking2' }];
```

And the following html markup:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCarPark" ng-options="cp.Name for cp in availableCarParks"></select>
```

For some reason, my dropdown is always empty...
When I do a "console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.availableCarParks))" the moment my controller gets initialized, I see a nice array of my objects like this (in chrome console):

```
[{"Id":"1","Name":"Parking1"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Parking2"}]
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? There must be something I'm overlooking...

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like similar to this. Also I have used a default selected value as well.

inside the **controller**:

```
    $scope.data = {
    availableCarParks : [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
    ],
    //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
    selectedOption: {id: '3', name: 'Option C'} 
    };
```

HTML **Markup**:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableCarParks track by option.id"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
```

Hope this will help you..

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change your ng-option directive input to:

```
ng-options="co.Id as cp.Name for cp in availableCarParks"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, what went wrong was that my variable (availablecarparks) didn't have any values in it yet when the view was rendered.
I created a function in my app config and did a route resolve to make sure the api call happened before the controller showed the view, and all is well now.